# Load external with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

While I'm on my way into learning the secrets of the beautiful world of Data Visualization, I'm encountering some difficulties with **D3.js** and the loading process of external data from a `csv` or a `json` file.

I'm kinda a newbie with JS so I'd like some help from experts.
Below my code:

```js
    var w = 500;
    var h = 500;

    // I'm setting up an empty array
    var csvData = [];

    //Create SVG element
    var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

    // Get the data
    d3.csv("csv/cities.csv", function(dataset) {
        for(var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
             csvData.push(dataset[i]);
        }
    });

    // Draw data
    svg.select("body").selectAll("p")
            .data(csvData)
            .enter()
            .append("p")
            .text(function(d) { return d });
```

Well, I'm not sure I did understand well the correct way to load data and process these values. Can someone be so kind to give me an hint? I have access to the `csvData` array (using the console from the developers tools) but I can't see any data returned with the `// Draw data` section.

This is the csv file:

```csv
csv/cities.csv

city,state,population,land area
seattle,WA,652405,83.9
new york,NY,8405837,302.6
boston,MA,645966,48.3
kansas city,MO,467007,315.0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet below is an ajax call which loads csv/cities.csv asynchronously:

```
// Get the data
d3.csv("csv/cities.csv", function(dataset) {
    for(var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
         csvData.push(dataset[i]);
    }
});
```

Thus the draw data section should have been like shown below:

```
  // Get the data
    d3.csv("csv/cities.csv", function(dataset) {
        for(var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
             csvData.push(dataset[i]);
        }
    // Draw data
    svg.select("body").selectAll("p")
            .data(csvData)
            .enter()
            .append("p")
            .text(function(d) { return d });
    });
```

Next Mistake:

You cannot add a p DOM inside SVG, that is the reason why you don't see the p DOM elements. I have appended the `p` DOM element into the body DOM that fixed the problem.

Working fiddle [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fi7yNqgCmpsGDpyAcCwy?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got your point and I did correct my code, including the "draw data" section into the "get the data". By the way, I'm not getting anything printed as "<p>" into my page... any wonder why this is happening?

Comment: Can you please check your network tab to see if the csv/cities.csv is loading up..I have a hunch that the file is not getting loaded

Comment: I can see it. Also, I can access to the csvData array from the console

Comment: Updated my answer check

Comment: Thanks, it all makes sense now :)